# RegEx to remove all \begin{gather}... \end{gather}

Tags: regex, latex

I have a 6,200 hundred pages book with simple stuff like:

```
\begin{gather}
    A>B,A=B,A<B,A\leq B,A \geq B
\end{gather}
```

or a bit more complicates:

```
\begin{gather}
    \begin{aligned}
    (a+b)^0&=1\\
    (a+b)^1&=1a+1b\\
    (a+b)^2&=1a^2+2ab+1b^2\\
    (a+b)^3&=1a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+1b^3\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

I'm trying to found the RegEx to remove all \begin{gather} \end{gather} environment (it's LaTeX). The best i have found by trial and error is:

```
(\\begin\{gather\}*\r?\n?.*)*\r?\n?.*(\r?\n?.*\\end\{gather\})
```

But it doesn't work :-(((

Any help would be appreciate.

Thx in advance

Comment: Try `(?s)\\begin\{gather}.*?\\end\{gather}`

Comment: Nope! At least in Notepad++ 7.4.1 that i used it seems to not work... :-((

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems to not work"? What exactly are you doing? You need to actually escape `}`: `(?s)\\begin\{gather\}.*?\\end\{gather\}` (it is the Boost regex detail I left out in my top comment) - and it will match the blocks in question. Then, just replace with an empty space, right?

Comment: I mean i the software just don't find any of the gather environment....

Comment: So, `(?s)\\begin\{gather\}.*?\\end\{gather\}` does match in Notepad++. What next?

Comment: You seem to just need `(?s)` (= *`.` matches newline* checked) and `.*?` lazy dot matching. A common issue.

Comment: Yes this was the issue! Thxxxx sooooo much. You saved my life instead of doing manually each of the 6,200 pages!!!! Ouahhhhhhhh! (you made my month!)

Answer (score 0):

This works in Notepad++:

```
(?s)\\begin\{gather\}.*?\\end\{gather\}
```

Make sure you set the option (. matches newline)

Here is an example in Regex101 that uses the ungreedy option ".*?" and the "(?s)" s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters.

[example](https://regex101.com/r/1FXia4/3)

Comment: Thanks but... If you take this MWE (minimum working example):

    `Bla bla bla:
     \begin{gather}
        A>B,A=B,A<B,A\leq B,A \geq B
     \end{gather}
     Bla bla bla bla:
     \begin{gather}\begin{aligned}
    (a+b)^0&=1\\
         (a+b)^1&=1a+1b\\
         (a+b)^2&=1a^2+2ab+1b^2\\
         (a+b)^3&=1a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+1b^3\\
        \end{aligned}
    \end{gather}`

He delete everything also what is outside the "gather" environment.